# `gsutlis ls` can't show bucket list

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, gsutil

I have 2 Mac laptops. I called them "MacA(works fine)" and "MacB(odd behavior)" in this question.

> What's happened in MacB?

1. Results of `gsutils ls`

   **MacA(works fine)**

   ```
   $ gsutil ls
   gs://bucket-a
   gs://bucket-b
   gs://bucket-c
   ```

   **MacB(odd behavior)**

   ```
   $ gsutil ls
   CommandException: Incorrect option(s) specified. Usage:

     gsutil ls [-a] [-b] [-d] [-l] [-L] [-r] [-p proj_id] url...

   For additional help run:
     gsutil help ls
   ```
2. Results of `gsutls help ls`

   **MacA(works fine)**

   ```
   $ gsutil help ls
   NAME
     ls - List providers, buckets, or objects

   SYNOPSIS

     gsutil ls [-a] [-b] [-d] [-l] [-L] [-r] [-p proj_id] url...

   LISTING PROVIDERS, BUCKETS, SUBDIRECTORIES, AND OBJECTS
     If you run gsutil ls without URLs, it lists all of the Google Cloud Storage
     buckets under your default project ID (or all of the Cloud Storage buckets
     under the project you specify with the -p flag):

       gsutil ls

     If you specify one or more provider URLs, gsutil ls lists buckets at each
     listed provider:
     ......
   ```

   **MacB(odd behavior)**

   ```
   $ gsutil help ls
   CommandException: The help command accepts at most 2 arguments. Usage:

     gsutil help [command or topic]

   For additional help run:
     gsutil help help
   ```
3. `shasum ~/google-cloud-sdk/bin/gsutil`

   Checksums of the ~/google-cloud-sdk/bin/gsutil are the same between MacA and MacB.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this problem.

My .zshrc had bad configuration.  I removed `-g` option.

`alias -g ls="ls -F -G"`

↓

`alias ls="ls -F -G"`

Before I changed .zshrc, `gsutil ls`  was replaced to `gsutils ls -F -G` unintentionally.